# Issues with batch file to upload to FTP

Tags: ftp, batch-file

I have currently created a `.bat` file to run a ftp command to upload documents to different locations. I need to have a lag time to ensure a response is received confirming data was posted successfully to the location.

Which occurs after the `dir Q__C` command.

Does anyone know of a command that I could use to that would wait for a response to be returned before proceeding to the next transfer request?

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ecggwprd.***.com
if20****
NvQ4*****
pwd
bin
"put \\msp06fil02\ACP_Finance_Ops\FTP\****.201602.zip  /m**_shadows_med/****.201602.zip
CD /m**_shadows_med
dir Q__C_"
```

Comment: is that what you are asking for?

Comment: I am running this thru a .bat file

Answer (score 0):

```
@ftp -i -s:"%~f0"&GOTO:EOF
open ecggwprd.***.com
if20****
NvQ4*****
pwd
bin
"put \\msp06fil02\ACP_Finance_Ops\FTP\****.201602.zip  /m**_shadows_med/****.201602.zip
CD /m**_shadows_med
dir Q__C_
!ping -n 3 0.0.0.0 > NULL"
```

Thanks for the good question. Here's hopefully a good answer. Were you aware that "ping" makes a great tool to provide pause like behavior which you're needing? The example I've provided will give you a 3 second pause. Not sure if it's needed before or after the dir command (Probably before). Anyhow, have fun experimenting with it though.

Cheers.